# How do I modify a linked list to hold a hash table? C++

Tags: c++, hash, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to make a stack of hash tables. The stack is meant to hold the hash tables. I want to have a stack (in this case List) of hash tables. Is there someway to put `H1` and `H2` into my `List One`? I'm planning to a make pop() and push() function for the stack of hash tables once I'm able to accomplish this. I'm also not allowed to use STL code on this program.

I may be overthinking something or missing something important. I'm not really sure if I'm going about it the right way.  I've been trying to figure it out, but I'm lost. I'm pretty fresh to all of this. I'd really enjoy a resolution for issue, thank you.

List.h

```
#include "Hashtable.h"
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

class List
{

private:

    typedef struct node
    {
      //stores the data in each node
      int data;
      //this creates a node pointer to point to another node in the list
      node* next;
    }*nodePtr;
    //the code above simplifies the code in the comment below
    //The code below code allows you to type "nodePtr"
    //instead of node* to make node
    //typedef struct node* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;

//functions in public access and manipulate the private section
//you don't actually access the private section
public:
    //constructor sets default values for our values: head, curr, and temp
    //putting the class name here let's the program know that we will set those
    //values when the list is created.
    List();//constructor
    //"void" so it returns no data
    void AddNode(int addData);
    //whatever value we pass through delData, 
    //the DeleteNode will fgo through the list and search for data that matches 
    //it and delete the node.
    void DeleteNode(int delData);
    void PrintList();
};

#endif /* LIST_H */
```

List.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

//now here you define the function from the class
//start out with class name "::" then the things you want to define from List.h
List::List()
{
    //values from Link.h
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void List::AddNode(int addData)
{
    nodePtr n = new node;
    //creating a new node pointer called "n" and a new node.
    // our new node pointer points to new node
    n->next = NULL;
    //find the node n is pointing to access it's next element and make 
    //that point to nothing
    n->data = addData;

    if(head != NULL)
    {
        //make the current pointer point to head(front of the list)
        curr  = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        //if it's not at the end of the list it will exit the while loop 
        //and point to "n" or the new node
        curr->next = n;
    }
    else
    {
        //if we don't have a list,the new node will be the front of the list.
        head = n;
    }

}

void List::DeleteNode(int delData)
{
    //now delPtr is the deletion pointer and points to nothing to start with
    nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    //while the current node isn't at the end of the list and isn't the data 
    //that needs to be deleted
    while(curr != NULL && curr->data != delData)
    {
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;  
    }
    if(curr == NULL)
    {
        //if we reach the end of the list
        cout << delData << " was not in the list \n";
        delete delPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        delPtr = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        temp->next = curr;

        if(delPtr == head)
        {
            head = head->next;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        delete delPtr;
        cout << "The value " << delData << " was deleted \n";
    }
}
void List::PrintList()
{
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
        //it'll keep moving to the next node until the end of the list
    }
}
```

Hashtable.h   Also, `name` is the data of the items placed in the hash table.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H

class HashTable
{
private:
    static const int tableSize = 10;
     //everything in the braces are what makes the item
    struct obj
    {
        int name;
        obj* next;
    };

    obj* HASHTBL[tableSize];

public:
    HashTable();
    //Hash is the function represents where in the hash table 
    //we will store the key
    //take a string stored in variable
    int Hash( int key);
    void AddObj(int name);
    int ItemsinBucket(int index);
    void PrintTable();
};


#endif /* HASHTABLE_H */
```

Hashtable.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "HashTable.h"

using namespace std;
//Takes from the HashTable class in HashTable.h
HashTable::HashTable()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < tableSize; x++)
    {
        HASHTBL[x] = new obj;
        HASHTBL[x]->name = NULL;
        HASHTBL[x]->next = NULL;
    }
}

void HashTable::AddObj( int name)
{
    int index = Hash(name);
    if(HASHTBL[index]->name == NULL)
    {  
        HASHTBL[index]->name = name;

    }
    else
    {
        obj* Ptr = HASHTBL[index];
        obj* n = new obj;
        n->name = name;
        n->next = NULL;
        while(Ptr->next !=NULL)
        {
            Ptr = Ptr->next;
        }
        Ptr->next = n;

    }
}

int HashTable::ItemsinBucket(int index)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (HASHTBL[index]->name == NULL)
    {
        return count;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
        obj* Ptr = HASHTBL[index];
        while(Ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            count++;
            Ptr = Ptr->next;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void HashTable::PrintTable()
{
    int number;
    for(int x = 0; x< tableSize; x++)
    {
        number = ItemsinBucket(x);
        cout << "------------------------\n";
        cout << "index = " << x << endl;
        cout << HASHTBL[x]->name << endl;
        cout << "The num of items in index  = "<< number << endl;
        cout << "------------------------\n";
    }
}


int HashTable::Hash(int key)
{
    //defining HashTable function:
    int HashTable = 0;
    int index;

   //will return integer value...or length of string you pass in

    for(int x = 0; x < key-1; x++)
    {
        HashTable = HashTable + x;
    }
    //so the hash table will take a number and mod it to return the remainder
    //the remainder is the index
    index = HashTable % tableSize;

    return index;

}
```

And, finally, main.cpp. The two hashtables are the tests `H1` and `H2`.  The `List One` is meant to be the stack the two hash tables go into.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "List.h"
#include "Hashtable.h"

using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    List One;

    One.AddNode(3);
    One.AddNode(5);
    One.AddNode(7);

    One.PrintList();
    One.DeleteNode(3);
    One.PrintList();



    HashTable H1;

    H1.AddObj(4);
    H1.AddObj(23);
    H1.AddObj(200);
    H1.AddObj(10);
    H1.AddObj(15);
    H1.AddObj(42);
    H1.AddObj(33);
    H1.AddObj(44);
    H1.AddObj(55);
    H1.AddObj(5);
    H1.AddObj(9);
    H1.AddObj(90);

    H1.PrintTable(); 


    HashTable H2;

    H2.AddObj(10);
    H2.AddObj(90);
    H2.AddObj(99);
    H2.AddObj(34);
    H2.AddObj(88);
    H2.AddObj(14);
    H2.AddObj(87);
    H2.AddObj(18);
    H2.AddObj(54);
    H2.AddObj(56);
    H2.AddObj(6);
    H2.AddObj(2);

}
```

This is the output. The top is the test of the list and a test of the `DeleteNode` function.

```
3
5
7
The value 3 was deleted 
5
7
------------------------
index = 0
42
The num of items in index  = 1
------------------------
------------------------
index = 1
23
The num of items in index  = 4
------------------------
------------------------
index = 2
0
The num of items in index  = 0
------------------------
------------------------
index = 3
4
The num of items in index  = 2
------------------------
------------------------
index = 4
0
The num of items in index  = 0
------------------------
------------------------
index = 5
0
The num of items in index  = 0
------------------------
------------------------
index = 6
10
The num of items in index  = 4
------------------------
------------------------
index = 7
0
The num of items in index  = 0
------------------------
------------------------
index = 8
9
The num of items in index  = 1
------------------------
------------------------
index = 9
0
The num of items in index  = 0
------------------------
```

Comment: you seem to already have a solution, is there any issue with it?

Comment: I don't know if I'm altogether thinking of stacks incorrectly, but I do have an issue. I want to have a stack (in this case `List` of hash tables. As in, is there someway to put `H1` and `H2` into my `List One`?

Comment: please edit the question then

Comment: your list holds ints (the List::node::data field) to make it hold hastables you probably need to modify it accordingly

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity. And yes, I suppose this is what I'm trying to figure out how to do. How am I to modify my list to hold the hash tables? I'm teaching myself, and I haven't found much in the way of that.